# Does it make sense to get a 529 plan to convert to Roth IRA in the future?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, roth-conversion, 529-plan

Given the recent changes on rolling over a 529 plan, could one start a 529 plan and then convert it to a Roth 15 years down the line if they don't use it for any schooling? I haven't considered 529 plans before and I am not sure if this is a loop hole and legal to do.

I am assuming with this approach one would:

1. be limited to having at most $35,000 in the 529 plan as this is the most that can be rolled over
2. would take `$35,000 / $6000 per year ~ 6 years` to rollover the lifetime limit to a Roth IRA assuming current IRA contribution limits.
3. would not need to save another $6000 during the years in (2) as the conversion counts as part of the limit.

Are my points above correct and is this legal?

Comment: Does your state give you a state tax break for the contributions? Do they pull this back if you don't use it for educational purposes? Does the state have a limit regarding how much you can contribute each year?

Comment: You're assuming that this rule is not going to be repealed before your 15 years holding period lapses...

Comment: @littleadv, how could it be repealed without grandfathering previous 529s?

Comment: @_mhoran_psprep, I need to look that up. Why are the tax breaks important though? What if the responses are no, yes and yes?

Comment: @heretoinfinity by an act of congress signed into law by POTUS.

Comment: @littleadv, I get that but I didn't realize that it could be done that way without accounting for what existed before. Does it mean that even traditional to roth ira conversions could be repealed?

Comment: Absolutely. In fact, similar mega-backdoor conversion (traditional to roth 401k) was on the chopping block as part of the BBB legislation, which ended up not passing.

Comment: @heretoinfinity. If you get a state tax break, and that is the thing that make your plan a money maker, but then you have to pay back the tax break that would be bad.

Comment: Thanks. That makes it less appealing.

Comment: Thanks @littleadv. Had that bill passed, then mega-backdoor conversion wouldn't have been allowed going forward even if you had accounts before the passing of the bill?

Comment: @heretoinfinity the conversion wouldn't have been allowed, not the account. So whatever after tax/traditional 401k you already had - would remain, and whatever Roth you already converted would remain, but the conversion wouldn't be allowed. Similar here, you may end up with a 529 balance, but you may end up not being able to convert because politics change and this is repealed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments to the question, it appears that it is not a good idea to get a 529 plan and expect to roll it over to a Roth IRA as there might be a law preventing such a conversion before one becomes eligible to do so.